# is it possible to have the inbuilt ServletContext Annotation inside the JAXB Binding class?

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

**The below is my JAXB Binding class which i am using during JAXB Unmarshalling process .**

```
package com;

@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CustAcct {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String cust;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String acct;



    public CustAcct() {

        super();
    }

    public String getCust() {

        return cust;
    }

    public void setCust(String s) {

        cust = s;
    }

    public String getAcct() {

        return acct;
    }

    public void setAcct(String s) {

        acct = s;
    }

}
```

**Now my question is that , i am unable to include the annotation @Context  ServletContext inside the above class .**

```
public class CustAcct {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String cust;


    @XmlAttribute
    private String acct;

                @Context
    ServletContext cont ;
```

I am getting the Exception , with this Message

```
javax.servlet.servletcontext is an interface and jaxb can't handle interfaces
```

Please let me know if is it possible to have the inbuilt ServletContext Annotation inside the JAXB Binding class ??

Thanks in advance .

**I tried this way ,**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CustAcct {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String acct;

    @XmlTransient
    @Context
    ServletContext con;

    public CustAcct() {

        super();
    }

    public String getAcct() {
    return acct;
    }

    public void setAcct(String s) {
    acct = s;
    }

}
```

But i am getting the following Exception when i am trying to access it inside a Jersey Service

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Containers can't inject `ServletConext` into domain objects. If you have to do anything on your domain objects with the ServletContext, you have to do it in Servlet's methods or JAX-RS resource's methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate that field with `@XmlTransient`.  This prevents your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation from treating it as mapped data.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: I have modified the question , please let me know whether i followed you correctly or not ??